# CharField choice show human-readable value

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I have little problem. I have models like Project and Member. Every project has members. In template I want to show user and his role in a specific project. It works but it shows me the number of role. I want to show human-readable value as  "Business Analyst" e.t.c. How can I take that values?

**models.py:**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Member', help_text=_('Members'))

class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)

ROLE_CHOICES = (
    ('1', _('Manager')),
    ('2', _('Developer')),
    ('3', _('Business Analyst')),
    ('4', _('System Analyst')),
)
```

**template**:

```
{% for member  in project.member_set.all %}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ member.user }}</td> <-- Example: Mark
        <td class="text-center">{{ member.role }}</td> <-- Example: 3 but I need Business Analyst
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read more on [get_FOO_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).

```
 <td class="text-center">{{ member.get_role_display }}</td>
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks for this link.